# Div will not display properly on mobile browser

Tags: html, css

I have a menu div and a maincontent div. It displays properly on IE and Chrome, but when I  view this on Opera on my Android phone, the menu div and maincontent div do not display the scrollbars, the divs stretch to fit the whole paragraph of text inside, leaving the menu div shorter than the maincontent div.

html:

```
<div id="contentwrap">
<div id="menu">
<p>Less text in here..............</p>
</div>

<div id="maincontent">
<p>More text in here.......</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I have specified that the menu and maincontent inherit their height from the contentwrap div so they should fill it?

I cannot work out though why this will not display properly, I have tried this with px and also percentage values and get the same result on the mobile browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/6LCGK/  - this displays fine on here, although on opera, the blue and green divs will not have scrollbars and will stretch to fit all content inside, this leaves the blue div shorter than the green div, exposing the pink coloured wrapper.

Anyone know what is going on?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your body at height 100% .

Comment: Yes I have already tried this before, this is not the solution.